# Импорт скриптов из Tilda в Nuxt

Tags: nuxt.js, tilda

Есть сайт на NuxtJS, на нем некоторые динамические страницы сверстаны в Тильде. Т.е. ранее дизайнеры создают страницу в Тильде, оттуда экспортируется 3 сущности: хтмл, цсс, жс.

[image: вот такие]

HTML мы вставляем в разметку, скрипты и стили в head.

Проблема заключается в том, что скрипты не отрабатывают. И, соответственно, если в странице тильды есть какой-то слайдер или анимация, то они не работают. Анимации, которые зашиты в стили, работают.

Есть ли способ решения проблемы в Nuxt?

Я пробовал создать тестовый обычный html файл и просто запустить его в браузере, все работает там.

Comment: мне кажется вы что-то странное делаете ))))

Comment: ну вот такая таска прилетела))

Answer (score 1):

если скрипты нужны для всех страниц тогда нужно добавить в `nuxt.config.js`.
примерно что-то подобное:

```
 head: {
    script: [
        {
            src: 'ссылка на ресурс'
        }
    ]
}
```

если для отдельной страницы, тогда так:

```
export default {
head() {
  return {
    script: [
      {
        src: 'ссылка на ресурс'
      }
    ],
  }
 }
}
```

Стили можно таким образом добавить. Если правите `nuxt.config.js` не забывайте перезапустить проект.

Есть один момент (раздел - ПРОБЛЕМА), можно [тут](https://webformyself.com/kak-zagruzit-storonnie-skripty-v-nuxt-js/) прочитать

Comment: Все вышеперечисленное пробовал, не работает. Скрипты нужны только на одной странице, на динамической, количество скриптов неизвестно. Но их всегда несколько. Чтобы понять, работает ли это вообще в принципе, я скрипты захардкодил пока. Но без результата. Раздел - ПРОБЛЕМА посмотрел. Там описывается как подгрузить один скрипт внешний, а вот как это сделать, когда их десяток, что-то ума не приложу...

Comment: после добавление таким образом, скрипт в разметке появился? Что у вас отображается? так никто не мешает несколько подгрузить

Comment: в разметке появились, но не отрабатывают

Comment: можете ссылки предоставить, чтобы у себя протестировать?